# Delete the minimum number of elements from a sequence so Lth element becomes the Kth Largest Strict Prefix Maximum

Tags: algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

Given a sequence of `N elements` delete the minimum number of elements from the sequence so that the element primarily sitting on `Lth position` (indexed from 1) becomes the `Kth largest` strict prefix maximum or print `-1` if it's impossible.

An element at index i is a strict prefix maximum if for all:

```
 j \< i, a\[j\] \< a\[i\]
```

Limits :

```
1 \<= L \<= N \<= 10^5

1 \<= K \<= 10

1 \<= A\[i\] \<= 10^9
```

I tried doing this by using dynamic programming but got stuck at a `O(n^2 \* k)` complexity.

Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: "Kth prefix maximum" like the title says, or "Kth largest prefix maximum", like the text says?